# Concentration inequalities for $P(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i > t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Let $\epsilon_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $X_i \sim \text{Normal}(0, \sigma^2 / n)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. I am interested in getting a sub-Gaussian type upper bound for
$$
P\left(\sum_i \epsilon_i X_i > t\right). 
$$
Ideally, it would look something like 
\begin{align}
P\left(\sum_i \epsilon_i X_i > t\right) \le K\exp\left(C\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2 p}\right) \tag{1}
\end{align}
for some constants $K$ and $C$, although I'm thinking this isn't true; I'm also not sure how to incorporate $n$ here into $K$ or $C$. It's important that the bound quantifies the deviation in terms of $p$, so that I have good control over what is going on as $p \to 0$. The furthest I've gotten is that, by iterated expectation and the usual Gaussian concentration stuff,
\begin{align}
P\left(\sum_i \epsilon_i X_i > t\right)
\le E\left\{\exp\left(\frac{-t^2 n}{2\sigma^2 \sum_i \epsilon_i}\right)\right\} \tag{2}
\end{align}
which, for fixed $p$, gives 
$$
\limsup_n P\left(\sum_i \epsilon_i X_i > t\right)
\le \exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2 p}\right)
$$
by the law of large numbers. But this approach doesn't seem strong enough, since a little bit of numeric investigation shows that (2) is quite a bit worse than (1) as $p \to 0$. Some quantification of how $p$ and $n$ play into the bound (2) would also be good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of incomplete thoughts on the problem that may be useful. In case it is useful for others to see how you derive $(2)$, and to get some quantified tradeoffs between $n$ and $p$, we have for any $\eta>0$,
\begin{align}
\Pr_{X,\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i>t\bigg)&=\mathbb{E}_{X,\epsilon}[\mathbf{1}\{\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i>t\}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\bigg[\Pr_X\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i>t\bigg)\bigg]\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon}\bigg[\exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon}\bigg)\bigg]\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n \exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2m}\bigg)\Pr_{\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i=m\bigg)\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{np+\eta}\exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2m}\bigg)\Pr_{\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i=m\bigg)+\sum_{m=np+\eta+1}^{n}\exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2m}\bigg)\Pr_{\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i=m\bigg)\\
&\leq \exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2(np+\eta)}\bigg)+\Pr_{\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m\epsilon_i>np +\eta\bigg)\exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg),
\end{align}
where we use the standard sub-Gaussian estimate $\Pr\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i>t\bigg)\leq \exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2 \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}\bigg)$ for the first inequality.

Recall one version of the multiplicative form of the Chernoff bound (just the one on Wikipedia): for $0\leq \delta\leq 1$,
$$
\Pr\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i>np(1+\delta)\bigg)\leq \exp\bigg(\frac{-\delta^2np}{3}\bigg).
$$
Letting $\eta=np\delta$ for $\delta\in [0,1]$, using this in the above bound becomes
$$
\Pr_{X,\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i>t\bigg)\leq \exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2p(1+\delta)}\bigg)+\exp\bigg(\frac{-\delta^2np}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg).
$$

This holds for all $n,p,$ and $0\leq \delta\leq 1$, and recovers your LLN bound as the second term vanishes as $n\to \infty$ when $\delta>0$, and then taking the limit as $\delta\to 0$. There is a weaker version with $0\leq \delta$, so $\delta$ could be chosen more judiciously for $n$ and $p$ if desired.

However, this bound doesn't capture the desired behavior that for any fixed $n$, as $p\to 0$, we should want the bound to tend to $0$. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to use these sorts of Chernoff bound to simultaneously get the proper large $n$, fixed $p$ behavior and $p\to 0$, $n$ fixed behavior. If the latter is the regime one is interested in, one can use the easy inequality,
$$
\Pr(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i>0)=1-(1-p)^n\leq np.
$$

Then the bound above would give for $p<1/n$, using $\eta=0$,
$$
\Pr_{X,\epsilon}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i X_i>t\bigg)\leq np\exp\bigg(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg),
$$
which at the very least goes to $0$ with $p$, but only like $p=\exp(\ln p)$ as opposed to $\exp(-1/p)$ as one would prefer.

Last point: one can try going through the normal proof of Chernoff bounds using MGFs, but it gets a little unwieldy to optimize the bound for generic $p$, except in the easy special cases of $p=1$ and $p=0$, where one exactly recovers the usual Gaussian bound. If one can make clever, tight approximations to the MGF that makes it easier to optimize, this could furnish an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note we can write the MGF of a single element in the sum in the following way:

$$ Ee^{t\epsilon X} = p E e^{tX} + (1-p) E e^0 = 1 - p + pe^{t^2 \sigma^2 / 2n} \le e^{t^2 \sigma^2 / 2n} $$
so the variable is $\sigma^2/n$-sub-Gaussian. Since they are independent, the sum is $\sigma^2$-sub-Gaussian and the standard tail bound gives
$$ \Pr(\sum_i \epsilon_i X_i > t) \le e^{-t^2 / 2 \sigma^2}. $$